# jQuery, Variables and Live Event Handlers

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery

I have two pages: the main one calls the other via AJAX to get a list of checkboxes.  When I try to get a count of checked checkboxes on the main page, I can only do it if I use inline jQuery -- trying to get it through a variable I initialize in **`$(document.ready())`** doesn't work.

Here's the main page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
        <script>
        var MyDiv, CheckedCheckboxes;
        var bIsLoading;

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("input:checkbox[name='SomeChoice']").live("click", function(){
                ShowCheckboxCount();
            });

            MyDiv = $("#MyDiv");
            CheckedCheckboxes = MyDiv.find("input:checkbox[name='SomeChoice']:checked");
            bIsLoading = false;
        });

        function ShowCheckboxCount()
        {
            var countUsingVariable = CheckedCheckboxes.length;
            var countUsingInline = $("#MyDiv").find("input:checkbox[name='SomeChoice']:checked").length;

            var alertMsg = (
                '# of checked checkboxes (using MyDiv variable) = ' + countUsingVariable + '\n' + 
                '# of checked checkboxes (using inline jQuery) = ' + countUsingInline
            );

            alert(alertMsg);
        }

        function LoadCheckboxes()
        {
            if (bIsLoading)
            {
                alert('Options are still loading.');
                return;
            }

            bIsLoading = true;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "html",
                url: "GetGuidOptions.asp",
                data: "",
                timeout: 5000,
                success: function(data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest){
                    $('#MyDiv').html(data);
                },
                error: function(XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert('An error occurred while attempting to load the options.');
                },
                complete: function(XmlHttpRequest, textStatus) {
                    bIsLoading = false;
                }
            });
        }
        </script>

        <form id="MyForm" name="MyForm">

        <div id="MyDiv">
        </div>

        <input type="button" value="Load Checkboxes" onclick="LoadCheckboxes()">
        <input type="button" value="Show Checkbox Count" onclick="ShowCheckboxCount()">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's the second page -- it's written in VBScript/ASP, but can be done easily enough using any server-side language:

```
<%
    Option Explicit

    '##################################################################################
    '// GetAlphanumericGUID() - Generate a GUID containing only letters and numbers.
    '##################################################################################
    Function GetAlphanumericGUID()
        Dim oTypeLib, sGUID, oRegEx, sAlphanumericGUID

        '// Generate a GUID.
        Set oTypeLib = Server.CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib")
            sGUID = Trim(Left(oTypeLib.GUID, 38))
        Set oTypeLib = nothing

        '// Remove all non-alphanumeric characters from the GUID.
        Set oRegEx = New RegExp
            oRegEx.Pattern = "\W"
            oRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
            oRegEx.Global = True
            sAlphanumericGUID = Replace(oRegEx.Replace(sGUID, ""), "_", "")
        Set oRegEx = Nothing

        GetAlphanumericGUID = sAlphanumericGUID
    End Function


    dim i, sValue
    for i = 1 to 10
        '// Generate a GUID string 5 characters in length
        sValue = Left(GetAlphanumericGUID(), 5) %>
<input type="checkbox" name="SomeChoice" value="<%=sValue%>"> <%=sValue%><br>
<%    next %>
```

Is there some way to get it to work so I can get the checked checkbox count using  **`CheckedCheckboxes.length`** instead of **`$("#MyDiv").find("input:checkbox[name='SomeChoice']:checked").length`**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in the way you're describing, no.  A jQuery selector is run once at creation time and creates a jQuery object containing the elements that match the selector.  Elements that match but are added later will not be part of the object.

Now, the `live` and `delegate` functions give a way to get around that, but they only work for event handling.  Basically, if you set an event handler using `live`, it catches all events (for all elements) and checks to see if the element triggering the event matches the given selector.  (So it doesn't matter whether that element existed at the time the `live` function was called originally.)

That doesn't give you a way to automatically keep a continuously updated list of checked boxes as you'd like to do, though.

Another approach would be to create a function that returns the list you want, and then use that (if your goal is to reduce typing/repetitive code):

```
function CheckedCheckboxes() {
    return MyDiv.find("input:checkbox[name='SomeChoice']:checked");
}

alert("Checked Boxes: " + CheckedCheckboxes().length);
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed breakdown, and sorry for the delay in responding.  It seems like one workaround would be to call **`CheckedCheckboxes = MyDiv.find("input:checkbox[name='SomeChoice']:checked");
`** in the **`success()`** method to refresh the variable.  But at least now I know that selectors are only run once at creation time.

Answer (score 1):

So basically what you're seeing is that the statement

```
$("#MyDiv").find("input:checkbox[name='SomeChoice']:checked")
```

resolves (executes) when it's called.  You're sort of trying to delay the execution.  One thing you could do is just save the selector in a variable and use that:

```
var selector = "input:checkbox[name='SomeChoice']:checked";
...
$('#MyDiv').find(selector).length;
```

Comment: That would definitely cut down on duplicate code.  But just to clarify: it wouldn't confer any type of performance boost, because you're still effectively passing the same selector every right, right?

Comment: Yep, same performance.  The first one just doesn't execute when you need it to.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can:

give all ur checkboxes the same `class`:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="SomeChoice" value="<%=sValue%>" class='someClass'> 
    <%=sValue%><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="SomeChoice" value="<%=sValue%>" class='someClass'> 
    <%=sValue%><br>
```

Then in js:

```
$('input.someClass:checked').length
```